# Ending a current requests execution immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an .net MVC application that uses a Single Sign On solution and an issue has been raised where the ASP.net session can expire (or the user can logout) but the SSO session is still valid. When this happen the app ends up in a strange state where it believes that the user is logged in, but the forms authentication doesn't.

In the an overidden `OnActionExecuting` method there are checks for this scenario, and if this is the case the application logs the user in with forms authentication, creating the cookie and attaching to the response etc. The final step of this process is to redirect back to the page they are currently requesting, ensuring that the `HttpContext` is correctly populated with the user etc, however, the call to original action continues processing, eventually causing an exception when it tries to access the current contexts user property.

So, is it possible to halt, without throwing another exception the current controllers execution, or is it possible to call some other function(s) that would then populate the Context?

Comment: We need some code my friend

Comment: you might be better off using custom authorization attribute to handle this

Comment: "however, the call to original action continues processing" if this is the case, then your "redirect" in `OnActionExecuting` isn't correctly "redirecting".   Please include the code for how you are redirecting from the filter.

Comment: response.Redirect(url, true);
                    response.End();
                    response.Flush();